# Can't add item using client object model of sharepoint 2010 with read only permission to user

Tags: client-object-model

I have already developed Silverlight application in SharePoint 2010 using client object model.

But I have one scenario that user can comment on the item, so there is a update operation come in picture for user, but **user have read only permission** to site.

So please help me resolved this problem.

We can use Run with elevated privileges method in SP object model. I think Silverlight client object model don’t support this method.

Is there any alternative workaround to solve this problem?

I can add/update/delete items from SharePoint 2010 List using Silverlight Client object model but if and only if user have full access to that list.

What if user has Read access to the list?

Error:
{Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerUnauthorizedAccessException: Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.SynchronousExecutor.Invoke()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.ExecuteQuery()
   at AllChannel.MainPage.bwSubscribe_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)}

Comment: Actually, i'm trying to retrieve list items from a list using a silverlight webpart, i can do so when i'm connected as an administrator but when i use anonymous acces i'm not able anymore to view results.

Answer (score 2):

You can create server code to do the update using elevated privileges and call it via web services.

Comment: Thanks Rob..

And already tried the same and its working fine.

Comment: Can you please specify more details,i'm new to webservices

Comment: MeYa check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521584.aspx , it might help you on right path